# "item has already Been added" added in audit

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, audit

I am trying to make Audit return logs, but always returns this error:

> "item has already Been added. Key in dictionary: 'mndo' Key Being added: 'mndo'"

I used these commands to test with a "test" user.

```
USE Clinica_Medica

SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE Nome = 'OI';
```

In Audit the log returns empty and with this error, I tried with the User SA standard, with global policies and the same happens.

My build:

[image]

[image]

Both are enabled, what I did wrong?

Comment: Which version of SSMS is this? Exact build number please.

Comment: SQL Server Express 2022 - v16.0.1050

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v19.0.1

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SSMS, maybe file it with Microsoft?

Comment: I think the bug would be in the SQL server, I opened a topic in Microsoft Community, but they didn't respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the audit profile in the C:/Audits folder, contained files from another instance of MicrosoftSQL db, was causing a conflict, this did not replace the file, I solved it by delting all the files in the folder.

Comment: I created a new empty folder for a new audit and this did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was fixed it installing last SQL 2022 update package (KB5026717).
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=105013

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Julio! This is your first answer, thank you for your insight, keep going. From my point of view it lacks information about the reasoning, it looks so general... Especially the description of KB5026717 seems to be not related to the mentioned error message. Could you be so kind and justify your answer?

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  I found the specific bug reference and updated the answer.